# Registering two types of users in 2 forms on same page, how to avoid refilling both form's inputs

Tags: laravel, validation, form-submit, registration

I have a little issue with registration validation errors in laravel (5.4). I have two forms for users registration (one for regular and one for business users) divided in 2 tabs. However when validation fails, both forms get filled with previously entered values in the fields, and errors show in both forms. I know that I should use the MessageBag but I don't know how to modify the register controller in order to do that. Could anyone help me to resolve this?
Forms have different ids, same action (/register).

This is the registration snippet in the RegisterController

```html
  public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all(), $request)));

        //$this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

Comment: Show us the blade with the form. You probably do `{!! Form::stuff !!}`?

Comment: @devk No, regular html, I just posted the blade as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#named-error-bags

```
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('user/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator,'register-user')
                        ->withInput();
        }
```

just set validation rules and url of the page

Comment: I added with input also, cos you want submitted input to be set

Comment: the problem is that Validator::make($data,$validateData ); is in the  protected function validator(array $data) so if I check the validator->fails here, when I call the validate function in register f-ion, i get error Method [validate] does not exist on Redirect. I don't know where exactly to make the validator->fails checking

Answer (score -1):

```html
 <form id="register-user"  class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input id="usertype" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="usertype" value="2">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="name"
                   class="col-md-4 control-label">{{Lang::get('translations.name', array(), $locale)}}</label>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required>
                </div>
                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```